# How to import data from one svelte file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

Sorry if I'm doing something wrong, I'm just starting with Svelte. I looked around on the web and couldn't find anything

I have a large hard coded data array made of objects that I want to keep in its own file while being able to access the data in app.svelte. I'm trying to keep my app.svelte as simple as possible. I tried `export const data=[{data:"mydata"}]` along with `import {data} from "./data.svelte"` but the `export` keyword means it expects the data to be sent over to data.svelte file, not the other way around. I really have no clue how to acheive this in Svelte. The data could also be json in a json file, as long as it is imported in my app.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.svelte` files should be reserverd for components only, you can add your data in a regular javascript file instead

in data.js

```js
export const data=[{data:"mydata"}]
```

in App.svelte

```
<script>
  import { data } from './data.js'
</script>
```

This is possible with json files as well, but it will require an extra step as svelte does not by default understand json files.  Depending on what bundler you use, you will have to add plugin, for Rollup this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-json